# space between horizontally aligned minipages

Tags: beamer, spacing, minipage

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{minipage}{0.4\paperwidth}
    \lipsum[1][1]
  \end{minipage}%                                                                                                                                                                                           
  %\hspace{0.1\paperwidth}%                                                                                                                                                                                 
  \begin{minipage}{0.4\paperwidth}
    \lipsum[1][2]
  \end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I use `%` in `\end{minipage}%` to force the minipages to be horizontally aligned.

However, in the output

[image]

the lack of space between the texts in the minipages is not appealing. I try to use `\hspace{0.1\paperwidth}%` to add space between the minipages ([How can I control the horizontal space between minipages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117983/how-can-i-control-the-horizontal-space-between-minipages?answertab=active#tab-top)). However, this fix causes the minipages to be placed one below another.

How to solve this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text width in the slide is shorter than 0.9x paper width. That's why the minipage goes to the next row. You can replace `\paperwidth` to `\textwidth`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    \lipsum[1][1]
  \end{minipage}%
  \hspace{0.1\textwidth}%
  \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
    \lipsum[1][2]
  \end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```